# Modal doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I made a modal using jQuery, but it doesn't seem to work properly. I'm calling my images in a javascript function, and the modal is in my window.onload in the same page the images are loaded. I'm loading the images first, but the modal only works if i put the imgs directly in the HTML and if i take everything else from the window.onload. That's how i'm calling all imgs:

```
function maisGaleria(n){

    var galeria = new Array();
    var img = document.querySelector("#gallery");
    var pic = 0;

        if(n == 1){
            pic = 4;
        }else if(n == 2){
            pic = 7;
        }else{
            pic = 4;
        }

        img.innerHTML = "<div class='row'>";
        img.innerHTML += "<div class='six columns'>";
        img.innerHTML += "<h4>Galeria "+n+"</h4>";

        for(var i = 0; i < pic; i++){
            galeria[i] = "foto"+n+"_"+(i+1)+".jpg";
        }

        for(var i = 0; i < galeria.length; i++){
            img.innerHTML += "<img src='img/"+galeria[i]+"' class='imgs-modal'>";
        }

        img.innerHTML += "</div>";
        img.innerHTML += "</div>";
}
```

and the window.onload with the modal:

```
        window.onload = function(){

        var rdSocial = document.querySelector("#social");
        var teste = document.querySelector("#teste");

            var fb = '<img src="img/fb.png" value="1" class="img" onclick="redireciona(this);">';
            var twt = '<img src="img/twitter.png" value="2" class="img" onclick="redireciona(this);">';
            var insta = '<img src="img/insta.png" value="3" class="img" onclick="redireciona(this);">';

            rdSocial.innerHTML += fb;
            rdSocial.innerHTML += twt;
            rdSocial.innerHTML += insta;

            var x = location.search.split("?gal=")[1];

            y = document.querySelector("#pics");

            //console.log(x);

            y.onload = maisGaleria(x);

//the modal starts here
                    $('.imgs-modal').on('click', function(){

                        var obj = $(this).clone();
                        console.log(obj);

                        $("#box_modal").html(obj);
                        $("#modal").fadeIn(1000);                   
                    });

                    $(".fechar").on('click', function(){
                        $("#modal").fadeOut(1000);
                    });

    }
```

Comment: Can you make a JS fiddle for it?

Comment: for starters, inject all your html into the DOM at once.....`img.innerHTML += "</div>";`  = dont do that.  build what youre injecting out on a var and after you've done all your bulding, then inject it.  also, try using `insertAdjacentHTML` instead of just modding innerHTML

Comment: You are appending event listeners before the "onload" event.

Comment: The jsfiddle are here: https://jsfiddle.net/qcxd7cta/

Comment: The thing is that i can't insert the images in the HTML, i need to put then dynamically...

Comment: Append event listerners inside the "maisGaleria" function

Comment: @WédneyYuri i don't get it. How i'm appeding it before ? All the imgs show up correctly... ALso when i append it inside that function it also doesn't work...

Comment: Sorry @anuseranother your example is broken.

Comment: I solved it. It seems i was having some kind of problem putting jQuery and JS in the same functions file. Just changed it and works fine now, with the modal inside the maisGaleria function. thanks !

Answer (score 1):

@anuseranother there are few errors in you code.

Before calling maisGaleria method in window.onload, you have to declare/define it.

As per your jsfiddle, it is throwing errors like maisGaleria is not defined. So define maisGaleria it before using it.

After fixing this error, another error is "Cannot set property 'onload' of null". There is no #pics element in the dom (y = document.querySelector("#pics")) and you are referencing it and adding onload method to it. Please update these two and let us know exactly how you need a modal with images any example in internet.